# create a row gap or break the sections in the report using r2rtf package

Tags: r

Could you please help with getting the row gap or break line between the sections displayed in the report? I am using the `r2rtf` package along with `tidyverse`.

For example using mtcars I have a column `rowname` I want to display the data with gap between these rownames

```
mtcars$rowname <- rowname(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
rtf_body() %>%
rtf_encode() %>%
write_rtf('cars.rtf')
```

[image]

Comment: i am using the tidyverse & r2rtf package

Comment: Please add these to the question so that it is reproducible, thankyou. And can you include a sketch of your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be handled in data manipulation step using `dplyr` before `r2rtf`.

You just need to add `\n` at the end of each value.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) paste(as.character(x), "\n"))) %>%
  rtf_body() %>%
  rtf_encode() %>%
  write_rtf('cars.rtf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the `r2rtf` package, but you could try  with the `text_space_after` argument of `rtf_body`

```r
library(r2rtf)

mtcars$rowname <- row.names(mtcars)

mtcars[1:5, c("rowname", "mpg", "cyl")] |>  
  rtf_body(text_space_after = 200)  |> 
  rtf_encode() |> 
  write_rtf('cars.rtf')
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]